# Restrict all outbound connections to a specific interface, and block if unavailable

Tags: iptables, firewall, centos7, firewalld, firewall-cmd

I'm running Centos 7 in a VM (I don't believe this should matter, but for context...)

Inside the VM, I'm running software to establish a tunnel. I can already accept connections from the host okay, but I want to force all outbound traffic over the tunnel.

How can I allow return packets for existing connections, while also ensuring no new connections are established from the box unless over tun0?

I've looked at this question [iptables blocking all outbound connections](https://serverfault.com/questions/596908/iptables-blocking-all-outbound-connections) but it appears a bit brute-force... I've been using `firewall-cmd` and the output for `iptables -L -n -v` is verbose.

Conversely, with [Use specific interface for outbound connections (Ubuntu 9.04)](https://serverfault.com/questions/41077/use-specific-interface-for-outbound-connections-ubuntu-9-04), I can't see how to apply it to centos.

How can I reliably ensure that all outbound traffic is either established over tun0 or not at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would effectively prevent any outgoing (IPv4) traffic except on tun0.

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Be aware that this will prevent **any** outbound traffic on **any** interface except tun0, which includes DHCP traffic, established SSH tunnels or the outbound packets from your established tunnel.

This can similarly be applied to IPv6 using `ip6tables`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My initial concerns were: I use firewall-cmd for everything else and I didn't want to impact the umpteen tables it uses (and/or were setup by Centos by default). Also, this doesn't address inbound from local. That said, the more I think about it, the more I think this sidesteps both issues by only trashing the OUTPUT table. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know firewall-cmd but this clears the OUTPUT table (optional), adds a rule that allows outbound traffic on the specficied interface and denies all other outbound traffic (done by policy in the above example, could be just a rule). Similar rules can be applied to the INPUT table. If you want to restrict network flows without adding rules to your firewall, contact a security vendor who'll hapilly sell you snake oil that does magic.